# Java run time error

Tags: java

I have this problem when I run my program in java.However I have main method ,I have saved My file with the name of MyClass and run it in a right path.thanks in advance..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:MyClass
caused by:java.lang.classNotFoundException:MyClass
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown sourse)
at java.security.AccessCountroller.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown sourse)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown sourse)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown sourse)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown sourse)
could not find the main class:Myclass.program will exit
```

Comment: did you add the file to project?

Comment: If you don't post the code for the main method we can't really help you.  Also, please tell us how you're compiling the code.  Is it part of an eclipse project, ant, etc.

Comment: A bit more information would be useful. For now it seems that your trying to run a .java file in Java.

Comment: Just wanted to say, main thread does not imply main method.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder about this:

```
main class:Myclass.program
```

`Myclass` is *not* the same as `MyClass`.  Java is case sensitive.